# All hard drive folders are write protected

Tags: windows, hard-drive, backup, write-protect

Recently, I had to put a backup from my old hard drive to a new one because it broke. But when the backup was on the new one, all folders had write protection.

[Example of my Documents folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NivsA.png)

I tryed removing the write protection one by one, but after removing it, its instantaniously back.

I also tryed to edit the Regedit configurations but there were none. I followed 
[this question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/external-hard-drive-remove-write-protection/6320592e-3986-4e9a-9df2-ab0d1e8e85cc).

Taking owner ship of the folder also didnt worked.

Im working with Windows-10 and made the backup with "HDClone 6 Free Edition"

Answer (score 0):

By default, most of your folders themselves on any Windows PC that Windows makes are read-only.  However, that does not mean you can't place both files and folders inside them.  Just copy the contents of the folders to your new drive.  You really don't want to start changing all the permissions on folders for this reason.

Had you used, or you could probably still use, Windows Image Backup, you wouldn't have to copy and files or folders back to your new drive.

Comment: My custom made Gamesfolder was not write protected on my old hard drive but is now. And i cannot remove the write protection. And even if I try to make new folders on the hard drive, they are instantly write protected. The hard drive itself is not write protected thoe.